# For Each Loop getting Last record name into TextView

Tags: java, android, foreach

Getting only last category name instead of all unique categories into TextView

```
Set<String> uniqueCategories; // global

......

uniqueCategories = new TreeSet<>();

for(Checkout c : checkOutArrayList) {
    uniqueCategories.add(c.getCategory());
}           

for (String strGlobalCategory : uniqueCategories) {
    System.out.println("Unique:"+strGlobalCategory);
    textVisible.setText(strGlobalCategory); // getting name of last Category only
    }
```

And when i am using `textVisitCharges.setText(strGlobalCategory);` out of for each loop getting `strGlobalCategory` cannot be resolved to a variable

Comment: what did expect to happen ?

Comment: It will do exactly what you want

Comment: @Blackbelt like to see all unique categories in a TextView as getting in log

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should append all categories to a single `String` and assign the result to the `TextView` :

```
StrinbBuilder text = new StringBuilder();
boolean first = true;
for (String strGlobalCategory : uniqueCategories) {
    if (!first) {
        text.append(", ");
    }
    first = false;
    text.append (strGlobalCategory);
}
textVisible.setText(text.toSTring());
```

Comment: text.append (" "+strGlobalCategory + ", "); but it showing , at the end  even no more categories available

Comment: @Oreo There were no commas in my original answer. If you want commas, see edited answer.

Answer (score 1):

`setText` always replace old text with current text.

You can use [append](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#append(java.lang.CharSequence)) for see all categories.

like

```
for (String strGlobalCategory : uniqueCategories) {
    System.out.println("Unique:"+strGlobalCategory);
    textVisible.append(strGlobalCategory+", "); // Now you will have all categories
}
```

Comment: I think we need textVisible.setText(null) before the for each to clear current text.

Answer (score 0):

```
        Set<String> uniqueCategories; // global
         //Suppose your set of string is like that
        String checkOutArrayList[]={"c","e","i","f","a","g","b","d","j","h"};
        uniqueCategories = new TreeSet<String>();

        for(String c : checkOutArrayList) {
            uniqueCategories.add(c);
        }        

        StringBuilder sb=new StringBuilder();
        sb.append("");//This blank text does not show null when set is empty
        for (String strGlobalCategory : uniqueCategories) {
            sb.append(strGlobalCategory);
            //sb.append(strGlobalCategory+" ");
            //sb.append(strGlobalCategory+"\n");
            //sb.append(strGlobalCategory+"\t");
        }


        //If you want to write the text without space your string is abcdefghij
        //If you want to write the text with space your string is a b c d e f g h i j
        //If you want to write the text with next line your string is 
        /*
            a
            b
            c
            ...
         */
        //If you want to write the text with tab your string is a   b   c   d   e   f......

        //In this way you can set all the set element with different ways...
          textVisible.setText(sb);

        //Your all set element is not appendign because the value is updated each time and the is showing
```